# populating and extracting data from an array of bytes

Tags: c#

Helly,

I have an array of byte `byte[] allbyte` that has multiple pdf files in byte array, my question is how can i get each pdf file `allbyte`

Comment: You can't. Sound like you tried to FTP a bunch of PDF files together.  You need to put a byte count a beginning of each file so you can tell where each file ends and the next begins.

Comment: you can search for header signature of pdf files